# addClass on hover for multiple items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I've been working on this script all day and all the examples I've seen just don't seem to do what I want. Here's my example [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xraQEB). Try to hover over "MENUS" and over "SETTINGS". I'll try to explain the problem with words:

**The Script:**

```
var activeItem = $("#menu .active");
var items = $("#menu .main:not(.active)");

activeItem.addClass("active-2");

items.hover(function () {
    "use strict";
    activeItem.toggleClass("active-2");
});

$(document).mousemove(function (event) {
    "use strict";
    if ($(".sub-1").css("background-clip").toLowerCase() == "content-box") {
        $(".sub-1").parents(".main").addClass("active-2");
        $(".sub-1").parents(".main").css("background-color", "#CCC");
    } else {
        $(".sub-1").parents(".main").removeClass("active-2");
        $(".sub-1").parents(".main").css("background-color", "");
    }
});
```

The above code gives the blue line (class `active-2`) to the active item. In this case "HOME". The `items` variable counts all main menu items that are not active and is used to toggle blue line (`active-2`) from "HOME" when other items are hovered. So far so good.

**The Problem:**

I have submenu items (the dark-grey ones). When the mouse is anywhere over these submenu items I want to give the parent main item the blue line (`active-2`) until the mouse leaves, then return the blue line to the currently active item `activeItem`, in this case "HOME".

When there is only **1** subitem group (like the one under "MENUS"), it works. But when I added a second submenu group (under "SETTINGS") it broke. I'm looking for a way to make it so no matter how many submenu groups I have the main item's blue line should be visible when my mouse is over it's submenu items and return to `activeItem` when I'm no longer hovering it. If you delete one of the `ul`s with class `.sub-1` under "MENUS" or "SETTINGS" with the inspector it will start working again.

**Why `mousemove`???**

I tried to `.addClass` in `.hover` and `.removeClass` in it's callback function but that didn't work... Or maybe I'm just not doing it right? So basically the only way I could think of achieving this effect was with `mousemove`, checking for meaningless CSS properties that are given to subitems only when they are visible:

```
#menu li:hover > ul {
    left: auto;
    background-clip: content-box;
}
```

So... I have no idea how to make it work in a meaningful way. Please help.

**Edit:**

Provided CodePen link at the top of the question.

Comment: Create a fiddle example of your problem with some sort of comment that where you are getting problem.So that we can check and rectify

Comment: I tried making a fiddle but there was some problem with my css. Here's a Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xraQEB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please in your codepen replace CSS line #329 with the following:

`#menu li.main:hover > a:before, #menu .active > a:before {`

And JS will be:

```
var activeItem = $("#menu .active");

items.hover(function () {
    activeItem.toggleClass("active");
});
```

Comment: This does indeed work, woah! But one more thing: when I hover on the MAIN menu items (these are "MENUS"/"SETTINGS"/"CONTACT") I want the blue line to disappear from  the `.active` item "HOME".

Comment: Ehh... Close enough. Check out the updated codepen for the way I made the code work. Thanks!